# How to run multiple files using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run multiple text files from folder on my desktop from which i have to search the word olympic and if it find olympic in that 50 text files than it should save it in output.txt , like 
textfile1 = 2
textfile2 = 1 and so on upto texfile=50

```
import glob
import re
write_file = open("output.txt")
flist = glob.glob("./*.py")   # adjust glob pattern as desired
print flist
print " lines : path to file"
for fpath in flist:
    with open(fpath) as f: #open files
        lines = f.readlines()
        if (lines == 'olympic'):
            write_file.write("%s" % lines) #write the results
        print "%6d : %s" % (len(lines),fpath)
        #with open securely opens and closes the file
write_file.close() # close file
```

This is what i am trying to do , but yes i know its full of error :)

i am trying to run multiple files , but not manually , i want that it automatically run the files of whole directory/folder and save their output in one text file..'`I have 50 text files and all files have word olympic , some have 1 some have 2/3 etc , i want to count the words from each text file and than save their output in one text file , like textfile1 = 2 , textfile2 = 3 etc in output.txt`

Comment: Whats your question exactly?

Comment: do you want to fetch line numbers, content of those lines or entire file content that has "olimpic" in it? your question is too ambiguous.

Comment: I have 50 text files and all files have word olympic , some have 1 some have 2/3 etc , i want to count the words from each text file and than save their output in one text file , like textfile1 = 2 , textfile2 = 3 etc in output.txt

Comment: If you want to get the total number of words in the file do `f = open('filename','r')`  `words_list = f.read().split()`  `num_words = len(words_list)`  For the total number of occurances of the word `olympic` do `words_list.count('olympic')` and `words_list.count('Olympic')`  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import re

filelist = [file for file in os.listdir('.') if '.py' in file]

for file in filelist:
  f = open(file,"r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    sum=0
    sum1=0
    for line in lines:
      if "olympics" in line:
        len(re.findall('\Wolympics\W', line))
        sum=sum+1
        print sum
      elif "Olympics" in line:
        sum1=sum1+1
        print sum1
    print "%6d : %s" % (len(line),file.name)
    f.close()
```

Not really sure what you're attempting to do, but I gave it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

**fetch.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


def get_counts(filepath, niddle):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read().count(niddle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    niddle = sys.argv[2]
    assert os.path.isdir(folder), "Not a folder"
    output = open('results.txt', 'w')
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if not filename.endswith('.html'): # or whatever
                continue
            filepath = os.path.abspath('%s/%s' % (dirpath, filename))
            result = '%s = %d' % (filepath, get_counts(filepath, niddle))
            output.write(result)
    output.close()
```

use as:

`$ python fetch.py /path/to/search olimpic`